# Where do VSCode extensions store their data files?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to manually edit the settings generated by a VSCode extension. Where can I find the actual files these settings are stored in?

Answer (score 1):

After much searching I found that they are in `~/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage`

There are also settings in `~/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json`